# php download zip folder as attachment, folder is not found

Tags: php

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this folder is not being found. I have a script that, after searching a database to find the `$filename` of someone's purchase based on a stored random code, should simply return their file. My code looks like this (including the trailing end of the db query):

```
            $stmt_2 -> bind_result($filename);
            $stmt_2 -> fetch();
            $stmt_2 -> close();
            
            // For .zip files

            $filepath='/media-files/Label/' . $filename;

            if (headers_sent()) {
                echo 'HTTP header already sent';
            } else {
                if (!is_file($filepath)) {
                    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
                    echo 'File not found.';
                } else if (!is_readable($filepath)) {
                    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
                    echo 'File not readable.';
                } else {
                    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filepath) . '"');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
                    readfile($filepath);
                    exit;   
                }
            }
```

When I run this code, I receive "File not found." so `!is_file($filepath)` is where it is getting tripped up -- However, the path is correct and the zip is definitely there, so I'm not sure what is wrong here.

In terms of debugging, I've tried removing the checks, going directly to the headers and readfile, which returns an empty zip folder. What does work is if I navigate directly to the file by URL...

**UPDATE**
The file path issue has been fixed, but I am still not able to download the file. In all attempts I get either `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` or if I try to brute force download the file, it returns an empty file. I tried using these headers with no success:

```
header_remove(); 
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
readfile($filepath);
ob_end_flush();
exit;
```

They are large audio files, which appears to be causing the issue...

Comment: have you try to debug your code? for example  a var dump for filepath variable?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is `/media-files` meant to be an **absolute** path, pointing to a folder way out of your application?

Comment: let's say the file is `file.zip`, then `var_dump` returns what I would have expected: `string(27) "/media-files/Label/file.zip"`. So it looks right to me. @Nico Haase, I was intending the path to be pointing from the root folder.

Comment: The code for this is also at root-level though.

Comment: What if you skip the verifications and let `readfile()` try to do its job? What error do you receive then? (obviously without the `@`)

Comment: Please share your debugging attempts. Also, please add all relevant information to your question by editing it

Comment: _“I was intending the path to be pointing from the root folder.”_ - are you talking about the _web_ root, or the _file system_ root? Are you aware of the difference?

Comment: Okay I've added some more details in the question -- basically skipping the checks confirms that the file is still not found because it returns an empty zip folder. I am just intending the file system root. Also, I am able to retrieve the file by brute force just going to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You have two types of pathes:

**(a)** The path of an URL. You have a web-adress which defines the root of your webpage.
e.g. https://www.stackoverflow.com is the start of the site. If you adress /questions at this site you always have the path https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions

**(b)** The path of the drive where the webpage is located. It is the filesystem-root.

e.g. /home/httpd/html/MyWebPage/questions

If you try to use /questions in (b) it will fail because *you need the whole path*.

So, this said you need to know where '/media-files/Label/'.$filename is located. It seems to me that /media-files is not at root-level of your filesystem (b).
Maybe it is at the web-root but this is not enough for your system to find the file. Therefore you need something like this:

'/root/httpd/MyWebPage/media-files/Label/'.$filename

Comment: What do you mean by "you need the whole path"? `/media-files/Label` is a perfectly valid folder name

Comment: This is the difference @CBroe mentioned too. There is a web root (a) and a file system root (b). This should not be messed up.

Comment: Then please share more details. There's no need to use `filepath` on a local file over HTTP

Comment: @NicoHaase Yeah - you are right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Nico Haase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116230/nico-haase) was absolutely correct, this is an issue with misunderstanding of paths. Here is a link to an article that should clear things up:
https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Currently your script is trying to find the file in:

> /media-files/Label/file.zip

not:

> /var/www/myproject/media-files/Label/file.zip

The linked article should provide you with all the neccesary information.

TLDR;

use:

```
$filepath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media-files/Label/' . $filename;
```

**UPDATE**

With the file size issue it might be that PHP runs out of allowed memory when trying to load the whole file. We could try something like:

```
flush();
$file = fopen($filepath, "r");
while(!feof($file)) {
    // send the current file part to the browser
    print fread($file, round(10 * 1024));
    // flush the content to the browser
    flush();
}
fclose($file);
```

There are some issues with flush() but it's a good shot I think. You can have a read on: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush

Other then that there is always the possibility to split the file into smaller chunks.

Comment: Thanks for the article - very interesting. But what I don't understand is that I was able to access e.g. PDF files before using this method... and when I use `$filepath= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/media-files/Label/' . $filename;` I actually get an `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`

Comment: Oh, but this means the file exists. So now there must be something wrong with the headers.

Comment: What framework and web server are you using? Can you try to dump the $filepath and put some debug text in the last else clause? that will tell us both is the $_SERVER variable is set on the server and if the file was found. Might be an issue with attaching the file now

Comment: framework/webserver, not sure exactly, I am just working on a small website for a friend -- hosting is anyway through FatCow. When I dump `$filepath`, I get a long prefix of folders (fascinating) `/home/users/web/` etc. etc. like that...and if I comment out the last `else` and just have `echo "file exists"`, then this is exactly what I see. So the file exists, which I something I guess.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#83653 this genius of a man implements a download limit. But other then that i love the way he uses flush() to send parts of information ie. headers->flush()->part1->flush()-->part2... that can fix a massive amount  of issues with server configurations.

Comment: Tried playing around with his code, but not having any luck :(  In all cases, either I get `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` or it downloads an empty file. HMm

Comment: did you try sending the file as header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); ? another approach might be trying to echo the file contents to the page itself. might be a file size issue, you could try send out something small at first

Comment: I updated my question with some new info -- will try now with a tiny file, that is a good idea.

Comment: Oh no, I think it is the file size :( they are large audio files -- I just zipped up a little pdf and I was able to download the zip file no problem...

Comment: Might be as simple as a memory issue. If that's the case then splitting the file into chunks like the download limit dude might fix it. I'll write the loop and update my answer in a minute

Comment: Have tried your code as well as many other variants I have searched in stackoverflow, but I seem to be getting nowhere :( Either the browser spins endlessly and times out after several minutes, or I get directly an `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` error page. Could something with the headers be messing this up?? Not sure what else to do...

Comment: Are you testing on a local environment or the destination server?

Comment: Testing directly on the live destination server

Comment: Just to make sure the code is working as intended test it on a local one. If it's ok there we'll be sure the code is fine and the server configuration is the issue. A local server might also provide some useful logs